# xsl:param and multiple filters

Tags: xslt, param

I'm trying to pass parameters (through c#) to the following XSLT to build a query with multiple filters but it is not working. What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to do this?

(The filter works with hard-coded values and the parameter values are getting through to the XSLT)

Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:param name="SensorBandName" />
  <xsl:param name="SensorBandFrequencyName" />
  <xsl:template match="Sensor">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>
          <xsl:value-of select="Bands/SensorBand[Name='$SensorBandName']/Frequencies/SensorBandFrequency[Name='$SensorBandFrequencyName']" />
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't quote the variable/parameter names!

```
<xsl:value-of select="Bands/SensorBand[Name=$SensorBandName]/Frequencies/SensorBandFrequency[Name=$SensorBandFrequencyName]" />
```

Comment: You're welcome. However, you could have accepted it as answer, being that I posted it a minute earlier than Rubens and that it is the same otherwise... ;)

Comment: I do agree, so I gave +1 to you

Comment: @Gerard - FYI - you can unselect an answer by clicking again and then select a different answer.